# Subplot changes size when I move legend: matlab

Tags: matlab, legend, handle, subplot

I created a plot of 11 subplots using

```
for stcount=1:11;
    subplot(4,3,stcounter);
.....stuff to plot

end
```

as the series being plotted are the same for all the plots, I added the legend at the end, thinking it would slot in to the final 'subplot position (4,3,12):

```
legend('series 1','series 2');
```

It didn't of course, because I realise now that it is only associated with the last subplot (4,3,11). I tried to manually move it and the final subplot resizes itself when I do this.
Does anyone know why?
I have tried saving the handle for the legend command:

```
h=legend('series 1','series 2');
```

and then trying to reposition the legend:

```
newPosition = [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5];%arbitrary position for example
newUnits = 'normalized';
set(h,'Position', newPosition,'Units', newUnits);
```

but `subplot(4,3,11)` keeps changing size.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to put the legend for all previous 11 groups of data into the last subplot?

Comment: yes. There are only two series used for all subplots representing the same metrics for different geographical areas: so one legend, (placed after all the subplots have been created) displaying the symbols/lines for those two series would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 sets of dummy data (`NaN`) and plot them in the last plot, and then add a legend.

```
for stcount=1:11;
    subplot(4,3,stcount);
    plot(1:10, rand(1,10), 'r-', 1:10, rand(1,10), 'k--');
end
subplot(4,3,12)
plot(1:10, nan(1,10), 'r-', 1:10, nan(1,10), 'k--');
axis off
legend('series 1', 'series 2');
```

[image: result]

The reason why you keep resizing subplot #11 is because in that way the legend is created as a *child* of #11. When you try to move it out of current display of the plot, Matlab just resize it to cover all the area where anything exists.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense,thanks. However, I would like for the subplot to not exist at all in the 4,3,12 position. I only want the legend to be there. If I delete subplot(4,3,12), then the legend will be deleted too.